# Auto-insert blank lines in `tail -f`

Tags: shell, awk, pipe, tail

Having a log file such as:

```
[DEBUG][2016-06-24 11:10:10,064][DataSourceImpl] - [line A...]
[DEBUG][2016-06-24 11:10:10,069][DataSourceImpl] - [line B...]
[DEBUG][2016-06-24 11:10:12,112][DataSourceImpl] - [line C...]
```

which is under `tail -f` real-time monitoring, is it possible to auto-insert (via a command we would pipe to the `tail`) "blank lines" after, let's say, 2 seconds of inactivity?

Expected result:

```
[DEBUG][2016-06-24 11:10:10,064][DataSourceImpl] - [line A...]
[DEBUG][2016-06-24 11:10:10,069][DataSourceImpl] - [line B...]
---
[DEBUG][2016-06-24 11:10:12,112][DataSourceImpl] - [line C...]
```

(because there is a gap of more than 2 seconds between 2 successive lines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F'[][\\- ,:]+' '1'
```

The above will split fields on `]`, `[`, `-`, `,`,  and `:`, so that each field is as described below:

```
[DEBUG][2016-06-24 11:10:10,064][DataSourceImpl] - [line A...]
 22222  3333 44 55 66 77 88 999  ...
```

You can then concatenate some of the fields and use that to measure time difference:

```
tail -f input.log | awk -F'[][\\- ,:]+' '{ curr=$3$4$5$6$7$8$9 }
                      prev + 2000 < curr { print "" } # Print empty line if two seconds 
                                                      # have passed since last record.
                                         { prev=curr } 1'
```

Comment: Wonderfully short!  Thanks a lot for this beautiful piece of art.

Comment: I realize I have some multi-line "events", ie first line with timestamp and all; following lines with no such prefix. How could you take that into account?

Comment: That won't behave as expected during DST or leap-day or leap-second transitions. That might be OK but something to be aware of.

Comment: Weirdly, I do have a blank line inserted at every minute transition, that is every 60 seconds (if there are other lines).

Answer (score 0):

`tail` does not have such feature. If you want you could implement a program or script that checks the last line of the file; something like (pseudocode)

```
previous_last_line = last line of your file
while(sleep 2 seconds)
    {
    if (last_line == previous_last_line)
        print newline
    else
        print lines since previous_last_line
    }
```

Two remarks:

- this will cause you to have no output during 2 seconds; you could keep checking for the last line more often and keep a timestamp; but that requires more code...
- this depends on the fact that all lines are unique; which is reasonable in your case; since you have timestamps in each line

Comment: In fact, the script shouldn't wait for 2 seconds. But be able to first insert a blank line if there has been no activity in the log for 2 seconds or more.

Comment: I know, that is an "undesired side-effect" of the script I proposed. As I said; you can think of another way of processing this; checking on the last line of the file more often; and outputting each line as you see it; keeping the timestamp of the last time you saw a line,... but that might get very resource-hungry very fast...